# How to extend Content Div to browser with

Tags: html, css, styles, stylesheet

below is my code,

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
  </div>

  <div class="right">
  </div>
</div>
```

i have set the width of my `wrapper` to 100% i have width for left as `40px`  now.

1) i want to extend my `right div` width as much as browser window  from `40px`  almost equal to 98.6% 
2)i want to extend my `left div` height as much as `right div` height

how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to understand your question,

but here are a couple of ways i think will answer your question

```
.right{
   width:calc(100% - 40px);
}
```

or you can do it this way

```
.right{
    height:100px;
    margin:0 20px;;
    background:#EEE;
}
```

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ConnorM/T2qSb/3/)

There isn't really a way to make a element the height of a different element unless you use `Javascript`

Answer (score 1):

Please try the css3 flexbox module, like this:

#### HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    left
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    right
  </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
html,body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display:-moz-box;
  display:-webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}
.left {
  width: 40px;
  background: green;
}
.right {
  -moz-flex-box: 1;
  -webkit-flex-box: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  background: orange;
}
```

Please view the [demo](http://codepen.io/airen/pen/DJGyu).About the CSS3 flexbox module, please click [here](http://www.w3cplus.com/blog/tags/157.html).